# Login issue in IOS Application it is giving me same profile every time when ever i hits to the server

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, iphone, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

My project is almost finished but now login Screen is became a big issue the problem is for example i create a new project with one class and rights the Login Part only using  **NSURLConnectionDelegate** Methods and run the project **i am getting my profile in JSON format it is correct** but now when **i run again and not typing any thing in to the textfields and clicks the SIGNIN Button it is giving me same response** i don't understand why is this happening can some one help me with this

This is the CODE

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError * error;
    jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonDictionary);
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}
- (IBAction)sigininAction:(id)sender {

    NSString *bodyData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user[email]=%@&user[password]=%@",[_email text],[_password text]];
    NSData *postData = [bodyData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL/login"]];
    [postRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [postRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [postRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
        theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
        if (theConnection) {
            [theConnection start];
            receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

        }
}
```

Comment: Try to inspect cookies you are sending. It is possible that NSURLConnection is managing them for you.

Comment: So u want to do check with cookies

Comment: You are absolutely right problem is cookies now my problem is solved thanks a lot and I change my code from nsurlconnection to nsurlsession and cookies to no it is working fine